# Customize "Show to" drop down labels in MySite Profile

Tags: user-profile, my-site, user-profile-property, my-profile

Is it possible to modify display texts for 'Show to' drop-downs in user profile editing page of mysite? If yes - where should I look?

[image: show to drop-down]

Answer (score 1):

The 5 privacy levels cannot be changed, added to, or removed. THe enumeration is static. The best you can hope for it to just change the labels as Alex shows above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working project I've created for you: http://www.4shared.com/rar/zs-Qg3BF/ReplaceSelectOptionsTitles.html. I suggest to use JQuery for this task. The main part of the solution:

```
function ReplaceSelectOptionsTitles() {
    $("select[title='Show To'] option[value='16']").text('choice 1');
    $("select[title='Show To'] option[value='8']").text('choice 2');
    $("select[title='Show To'] option[value='4']").text('choice 3');
    $("select[title='Show To'] option[value='2']").text('choice 4');
    $("select[title='Show To'] option[value='1']").text('choice 5');
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('ReplaceSelectOptionsTitles');
```

If you will use my solution you need to install the solution packet on the server and activate the feature on the profile web.